# Automated test Python/selenium gspread

Tags: python, selenium, google-sheets

For example, to view a Google Sheets document I can use `gspread`:

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.login("your login", "your password")
wks = gc.open("document name").worksheet("sheet name")

cellValue = wks.acell("A1").value
print "Cell 'A1' has a value of %s" % cellValue
```

Is there a way I can access Google Sheets and try to edit it in an automated test using Python and Selenium?

Comment: please clarify " access google sheets and try to edit it in an automated test using python and selenium "

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python

- Go to the above link and create a project by following the steps given with your google account.
- From the above link you will download **OAuth client ID** which will give you client_secret.json.
- In this example **OAuth client ID** is not used and it will be necessary while using other api.
- In addtion to above you have to download **Service Account Key** which will be below **OAuth client ID**. Download it as json.
- The path to **Service Account Key** has to be mentioned in the fourth line of the following code.

Code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
#scope is necessary if we are accesing gdrive
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/home/username/Downloads/MyProject.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

#to create a new gsheet
sh = gc.create('Sheet_1')

#to open existing gsheet
sh = gc.open('LYKE')

# to share to other users
sh.share('username@gmail.com', perm_type='user', role='writer')

#to create a worksheet in the gsheet
worksheet = sh.add_worksheet(title='title', rows="500", cols="50")

#Define a cell range and update cells
cell_list = worksheet.range('A1:A10')
for i,cell in enumerate(cell_list):
    cell.value=i
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```